# Docker connect to TCP port 1433 Erratically throws error "1433 An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions "

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tcp, tcp-port

At work, we have a Docker Compose YAML file will allow the programmer to run an MS SQL Server-based docker image as a container.

Please keep in mind that there are configurations for 3 images ( 2 Database images & 1 Hasura GraphQL image ) in said Docker Compose YAML file:

a) Microsoft SQL Server Database which is used by the application in question that is being developed

b) PostgreSQL database and a database instance specifically for storing Hasura's Metadata info data

c) Hasura GraphQL instance

Here are the steps that I take to run said YAML file in docker.

1. Start the docker desktop application.
2. Retrieve said Docker Compose YAML file, and place it in a directory on your local computer.
3. In this gitlab.com repo's Docker Compose YAML file, default HOST_PORT and CONTAINER_PORT numbers were entered, therefore, navigate to said directory within Microsoft Power Shell, and run the following command:

   docker-compose -f ms_sqlserverdocker-compose.yml up

Unfortunately, I sometime get the following error message Erratically when I run the Microsoft SQL Server Database container ( i.e. sql-server-db  )  :

[image]

The error states the following:
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:1433 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1433: bind: An attempt was made to
access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

( I usually resolve the aforementioned error by restarting my local computer which is really onerous because it’s sort a pain to restart the computer in order to to free up a port )

The aforementioned error comes up erratically in my local computer.

When I the following netstat command in my MS Dos commandline window, it returns nothing which is strange:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965] (c) Microsoft Corporation.
> All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>netstat -ano | find "1433"
>
> C:\Windows\system32>

If netstat searches for port 1433 , and return nothing then does it mean that port “1433” is available and open for use?  If yes then why is docker complaining with the following message when I attempt to connect to port 1433 within my local computer?

An attempt was made to
access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

( I usually resolve the aforementioned error by restarting my local computer which is really onerous because it’s sort a pain to restart the computer in order to to free up a port )

Does anyone know why the 1433 port becomes erratically unavailable?  Furthermore, is there a more elegant way of freeing up said port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to @eric-herlitz for his following webpage that contains the answer:

(Reference Citation Listing:   https://www.herlitz.io/2020/12/01/docker-error-ports-are-not-available-on-windows-10/  )

"Windows 10 can sometimes hog ports and sockets preventing us from using them with services like docker. This renders error like this

> docker : Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen
> tcp 0.0.0.0:1433: bind:  An attempt was made to access a socket in a
> way forbidden by its access permissions. At line:1 char:1
> +docker start sqlexpress
> +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error response ...ss permissions.:String) [], RemoteException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> Error: failed to start containers: sqlexpress

Stopping winnat

To fix this you must temporarily disable the winnat service, this is simply done by running this command (must be run as administrator)

> net stop winnat

Start your docker services and start winnat again

> net start winnat

"

(Reference Citation Listing:   https://www.herlitz.io/2020/12/01/docker-error-ports-are-not-available-on-windows-10/  )

Comment: Thanks, same problem on win11, worked !